# Set format month DatePicker extends DialogFragment

Tags: android, android-datepicker

How Can i format month of `DatePicker` on `DialogFragment`?
I've created this class that extends `DialogFragment`:

**DatePickerCustom**

```
public class DatePickerCustom extends DialogFragment
    implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {


    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

       final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
       int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
       int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
       int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
       month = month+1;

       return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
   }


   public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
      TextView datePickerText = (TextView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.date_picker_text);
      datePickerText.setText(day+" - "+month+" - "+year);

   }
}
```

In my activity i've created a function that show `DatePicker` when i touch icons or `TextView`:

```
public void showDatePickerDialog(View v) {
    DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerCustom();
    newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "datePicker");

}
```

In display I see date like: 22 - 7 - 2016 but i would have this format: 22 - **0**7 - 2016  so with 0 before month if it's < of 10

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a `Date` object from your values using `Calendar` and format it with an appropriate `SimpleDateFormat` instance.

Something like this:

```
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
    TextView datePickerText = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.date_picker_text);

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(year, month, day);

    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    String dateString = dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());

    datePickerText.setText(dateString);
}
```